# Upgrade MacBook Pro 2012 drive to high performance SSD or buy new 2016 MacBook Pro?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, ssd, macbook-pro

What do you guys think would reap the highest performance improvements?

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro with 
1,024 gb hard drive memory 
8 gb RAM 
2.9 GHZ Intel Core i7

I am wondering (in terms of performance) am I better off buying a new high performance SSD for my Mac or just buy a new 2016 MacBook Pro with the apple stock SSD?

I don't care about price very much. Just want to know which would perform better ?

Comment: @NMD Tech: I’m not sure whether I would have voted to close this question as “opinion-based”, but five people did, and I don’t feel like voting to reopen, especially after it’s five years old.   [Your changes](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1084896) were not an improvement (note: the word “I” should ***always*** be capitalized) and did not make the question any less opinion-based than it was originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Late 2011 MacBook Pro that I put an SSD in and upgraded my memory to 16gb.  I haven't felt the need to upgrade to a later model because this still does everything I've needed it to do.

I'd say if you're processor is still supporting what you need, upgrade your hard drive and memory and call it a day.